# Can't Update Data at MongoDB - using Next.js with Mongoose API

Tags: typescript, mongoose, next.js, crud, server-side-rendering

I am encountering an issue with a "PUT" request in a Next.js API. At first glance, the code appears to be correct, and when I test it using Postman, I receive a status success message as confirmation. However, the problem arises when I subsequently make a "GET" request for a post that I have just updated. The data remains unchanged, and the update doesn't seem to have taken effect. This API uses Mongoose for performing CRUD operations.

app/api/topics/[id]/route.js

```
export const PUT = async(request, {params}) => {
    try {
        const {id} = params
        const {title, description} = request.json()
        await ConnectMongoDB()
        await Topic.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {title, description})
        return NextResponse.json(
            {message: "Topic Updated"},
            {status: 200}
        )
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
        NextResponse.json(
            {message: "Internal Server Error"},
            {status: 500}
        )
    }
}
```

app/editTopics/[id]/page.tsx

```
'use client'

import { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react"
import { useParams,useRouter } from "next/navigation"

import Input, {Button} from "@/components/Input"

const getTopicById = async (id:string) => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/topics/" + id, {
            cache: "no-store"
        })

        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error("Failed to fetch a topic")
        }        
        return res.json()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

type Topic = {
    _id: string
    title: string
    description: string
}

type API_Response = {
    data: Topic
}

export default function EditTopic() {
    const params = useParams()
    const id = params.id as string
    console.log("id", id)

    const router = useRouter()

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchTopic() {
            const {response} = await getTopicById(id)
            setFormData(response.data)
        }
    }, [id])

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        title: "",
        description: ""
    })

    function handleInputChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>| React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>, name: string) {
        setFormData(form => ({
            ...form, [name]: e.target.value
        }))
    }

    async function handleSubmit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        e.preventDefault()

        try {
            const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/topics/${id}`, {
                method: "PUT",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    title: formData.title,
                    description: formData.title
                })
            })

            if (res.ok) {
                router.push("/")
            } else {
                throw new Error("Failed to update topic")
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    return(<>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="flex flex-col gap-3">    
        <Input mode="input" name="title" label="Title" 
          onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, "title")} 
          value={formData.title} 
          defaultValue={formData.title}
        />
        <Input mode="textarea" name="description" label="Description" 
          onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, "description")} 
          value={formData.description} 
          defaultValue={formData.description}
        />
        <Button>
            Update Topic
        </Button>
    </form>
    </>)
}
```

In the editTopics/[id] route, the form is not displaying the value stored in the database.

I have shared the remaining code on this [GitHub](https://github.com/agung343/nextjs_crud/) repository